# jquery automatic update two select fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two `select` boxes. One with list of Cities and the second one with Districts of Cities. When I chose (by click) the City from the first `select` box in the second box I see districts from selected City. That work perfectly, but when the City is selected automaticly by another script, the list of districts doesn't show - i have to manualy select the city from the list and then the list of districts appear.

Here is my script:

```
$.viewMap_get = {
    '0' : $([]),
    'Katowice' : $('#c1a, #c1b, #c6, #c7'),
    'Kraków' : $('#c2a, #c2b, #c6, #c7'),
    'Warszawa' : $('#c3a, #c3b, #c6, #c7'),
    'Wrocław' : $('#c4a, #c4b, #c6, #c7'),
    'Gdańsk' : $('#c5a, #c5b, #c6, #c7'),
};

$.each($.viewMap_get, function() { this.hide(); });
$('#get_city_district').hide();

$('#get_car').change(function() {
// hide all
$.each($.viewMap_get, function() { this.hide(); });
  $('#get_city_district').hide();
// show current
$.viewMap_get[$(this).val()].show();
  $('#get_city_district').show();
  var id = $.viewMap_get[$(this).val()].attr("id");   
  $('#'+id).attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should bind getting district of the selected city to

```
$('firstSelect').change(function(){
// your code
})
```

Comment: i try to to this but i don't know how

Comment: $('#yourFirstSelectId').change(function(){ 
$('#get_city_district').show(); 
})
Add this lines to your code & see if it helps